# Add hotkey shortcut to navbar link

Tags: javascript, html

I added 4 links on my navbar through JavaScript. How can I load those links by pressing keys 1-4 in my feeds `<iframe>` ?

```html
<li>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<a href="https://linkhere.com/blah.html?'+new Date().getTime()+'" target="feeds">1</a>');
</script>
</li>
<iframe name="feeds" width="50%" height="500"></iframe>
```

Comment: What is "the hot key #1"?

Comment: i wanna make it where i hit #1 on my keybord it loads the tab named "1" in my navigation bar

Comment: Please add all such explanation, and your attempts to resolve this, to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this code:

```js
document.addEventListener('keypress', function (event) {
        if (event.key === '1')
            document.getElementsByName('feeds')[0].src = 
        'https://linkhere.com/blah.html?'+new Date().getTime();
    });
```

```html
<iframe name="feeds" width="50%" height="500"></iframe>
```

Here we are setting up keyboard shortcut for key '1'. In the similar fashion you can add keyboard shortcuts for the other keys.

Comment: How would i assign it to open in the iframe named feeds tho?

Comment: and would i just wrap it around <li></li>

Comment: no i want blah.html to open up in a already existing iframe tho

Comment: then don't use that iframe, just add name=feeds attribute to your iframe

Comment: Sweet ill try it!

Comment: You need to place java script inside `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>` tags. This javascript works at document-level so it would be better if you place it inside the `<head>` section. Or if you are using external javascript file place it there in start.

Comment: i added that 
and when i press 1 nothing happens not sure what im doing wrong

Comment: view-source:https://bmx-tv.net/usw.html  i placed it on line #11

Comment: you need to show more of your code then, code where you added it and <iframe> code. You can even run my code in my answer here and check how it works.

Comment: what is that? cam site? are you kidding?

Comment: no its a Big Brother site and we have 6 feeds i am wanting the cams to Switch when i use hot key 1 hot key 2 Hot key 3 theres 6 cams

Comment: like on the navbar when you click 1,2,3,4,q,j it loads in the iframe im wanting those to also be controlled by 1,2,3,4,5,6 on the keybord i guess if that makes sense?

Comment: You have lots of mistake in your code. Your body section as well as another head section starting inside your first head section. You have added `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">` inside your head section. `<style>` instead of head section, starting in body section. Your first `<meta>` tag is out of head section.

Comment: What line should the Hotkey script you wrote be placed in?

Comment: You placed it right, but you head and body contains lot of mistakes.

Comment: everything works tho besides hotkey thats all im really trying to get working atm the rest if the code has worked for what im needing but i do need to try to fix all that eventually

Comment: do you know any code sharing site? I can rewrite your code and send you back and you can check it. You can run my code here. It is running fine.

Comment: Its midnight and I got to sleep. I told you about bugs in your code. You have 2 head and 2 body sections. Also try to consolidate things instead of putting each javascript section in seperate `<script>` tags. Finally I think you should up-vote and tick my answer as I solved problem which you said. If you want any further help about your code, message me. I will see it later. Happy Coding

Comment: Haven't seen your message. Is it emergency or can we work on it tomorrow ? Its midnight 12 pm here.

Comment: Yeah for sure man get some sleep and ill be happy to mark your answer :) i just trying to make the answer work first and when i get it figured out ill mark ya for sure you rock man thanks

Comment: Mark, I checked your code and found out it is generated by software. First you need to remove `onkeydown="return false;"`from your `<body> tag`. You also importing lots of script. Check where else this software do the same. You also importing that `feeds` iFrame. In your document there is a iFrame with id `div1` which loads page which contains iFrame `holder` which loads page which contains iFrame `feeds`. I figured out how to access its elements but your code is full of errors. Idk where else in the code you denying `onkeydown` events by returning false.